# Add an extra argument to capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to add an extra argument to Capistrano so we can query a central server via API to get the target:

```
cap production deploy target
```

Everything works great, target is preprocessed (in config/deploy/production.rb) and the correct server is found via API (determined by target), and the deploy completes successfully. However, at the end of the deploy, I get an error:

(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'target' (See the list of available tasks with `cap --tasks`)

```
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Don't know how to build task 'target' (See the list of available tasks with `cap --tasks`)
```

Is there any way to get rid of this error?

FYI, the way we use the 3rd argument (target) in production.rb is to use ARGV, then we do a lookup to a central server with HTTParty.  The idea is that we need to deploy to 20+ servers and rather than have one deploy file for each new server, just use an API to get the targets.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

If that's the end of your task you can put `exit` on the last line and it won't print that error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capistrano User Input.

> User input can be required in a task or during configuration.

Use the capistrano default deploy command and ask for user input inside config/deploy/production.rb

```
cap production deploy
```

E.g.

```
ask(:target, nil, prompt: 'Enter target') # Prompting for user input
target = fetch(:target)
```

> ask will not prompt the user immediately. The question is deferred until the first time fetch is used to obtain the setting.

For more information check out the documentation here: [Capistrano User Input](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/user-input/)